# How to keep unknown local offset when converting from RFC3339?

Tags: java, timestamp, java-time, rfc3339, offsetdatetime

I recieve a timestamp that follows the RFC3339 standard. The sender used the "Unknown Local Offset Convention" provided by RFC3339 as the users time preference is unkown, so I recieve a timestamp like `1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000-00:00` and I need to preserve the `-00:00` information. I am currenlty parsing the recieved timestamp with

```
LocalDateTime localTimeStamp = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
OffsetDateTime.of(localTimeStamp, ZoneOffset.of("-00:00"))
```

but this replaces the `-00:00` with `Z`. Is there a way to keep the unkown local offset convetion, ideally with `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: LocalDateTime uses the ISO-8601 model.  Although RFC-3339 is largely identical, this is one of the disparities between them.  Specifically, a negative zero offset is not allowed under ISO-8601.  My guess is that Java is making a good faith effort to translate this and makes +00:00 instead (i.e. Z).  You may need a custom class to handle this format.

Comment: java.time handles a UTC offset as a count of seconds within +/- 18 hours so does not distinguish -0 from +0 (and renders 0 as `Z` as you have observed) and hence also does not support an unknown offset. Before parsing you may want an `if`-`else` construct with a condition like `timeStamp.matches(".*-[0:]+")` to filter out the timestamps that have an offset of minus 0, that is, unknown in RFC 3339. (I'm unsure about RFC 3339, but `OffsetDateTime.parse(CharSequence)` also accepts `-00:00:00` as an offset, and future releases may accept even more forms.)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime
.parse( 
    "1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000-00:00"
    .replace( "-00:00" , "" )
)
```

## Avoid RFC 3339

[RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339.html) is a self-proclaimed “profile” of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Unfortunately, RFC 3339 defines some unwise violations of that standard.

One of these violations is allowing an offset from UTC of *negative* zero hours-minutes-seconds. In contrast, ISO 8601 wisely forbids such a negative zero.

In the RFC the meaning of a negative zero offset is that the true offset is unknown. To quote the RFC:

> 4.3. Unknown Local Offset Convention
>
> If the time in UTC is known, but the offset to local time is unknown, this can be represented with an offset of "-00:00".  This differs semantically from an offset of "Z" or "+00:00", which imply that UTC is the preferred reference point for the specified time.  [RFC2822 [IMAIL-UPDATE]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) describes a similar convention for email.

In contrast, in ISO 8601 an unknown offset is simply omitted. Omission seems a much smarter course.

I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the poor decisions employed in RFC 3339, and recommend they stick to ISO 8601 definitions.

### `LocalDateTime` class

If you must parse strings with the negative zero offset, I suggest you perform simple string manipulation to strip it. Replace the `-00:00` with empty string. Then parse as a `LocalDateTime` which purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset. A `LocalDateTime` is simply a date with a time-of-day, nothing more.

```
String input = "1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000-00:00" ;
String modified = input.replace( "-00:00" , "" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( modified ) ;
```

You asked:

> Is there a way to keep the unkown local offset convetion, ideally with OffsetDateTime?

Using `OffsetDateTime` here makes no sense. That class represents a date and time as seen with with a particular offset. But you don’t know the intended offset. So **you have only two of the three pieces** required by `OffsetDateTime`.

Instead, `LocalDateTime` fits your need to represent a date and time without the context of an offset or time zone.

Comment: The strange offset `-00:00` is supposed to follow a time in UTC, according to the RFC. For all but the slightest intents and purposes, you ought to treat `-00:00` like it was `+00:00`.

Comment: @eksortso No, you are very much incorrect. I added a quotation from the RFC saying just the opposite of your comment. A `-00:00` in RFC 3339 means ***unknown offset*** whereas `+00:00` means a ***known offset of zero***. You absolutely should *not* “treat -00:00 like it was +00:00”. They mean totally different things in RFC 3339, and in ISO 8601 one of the two does not exist. In terms of Java classes, this duality is be matched by `LocalDateTime` class which has no concept of offset or zone, and `Instant` class that represents a specific point on the timeline as seen from an offset of zero.

Comment: @BasilBourque Hmm? The quote says: "If the time in UTC is known". The absolute time (in UTC) is known, but it **cannot** be converted to a local time since the local timezone is unknown. Treating it as if it was a local time is therefore more or less the worst thing you could do, since its representation in local time is just the one thing you *don't* know (while do you know the absolute time, which on the other hand is unknown in `LocalDateTime`s).